# ActiveMQ broker gets constant null message pull attempts from a consumer

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, message-queue, messaging

I have two ActiveMQ brokers with one consumer. The consumer's connection configuration is set to failover with either of the brokers. On one of the brokers I get a constant message pull log:

> INFO  LoggingBrokerPlugin            - Message Pull from: ID:CONSUMER_HOST-40120-1559830731356-0:1 on queue:QUEUE_NAME
>
> INFO  LoggingBrokerPlugin            - preProcessDispatch: MessageDispatch {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, consumerId = ID:CONSUMER_HOST-40120-1559830731356-1:1:1:1, destination = null, message = null, redeliveryCounter = 0}

There are approximately two entries like that per second. I purged the queue, restarted both nodes and restarted the consumer.

Is it a normal behaviour? Is it just a normal polling for any new messages or is there something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client will perform a pull only when configured with a zero prefetch size and you call one of the receive methods.  You would need to look at your client and how it is being used the answer why the pulls happen so often, likely you are calling receive in a loop or something along those lines.